# typescript: overload based on a func param count

Tags: typescript, overloading

I want to implement the following:

> Make a function F, which accepts a function G as first argument, and:
>
> - if G has 1 or more params, F accepts that parameters list as second argument
> - if G has 0 params, F doesn't accept anything else

My first naive attempt to achieve it was this:

```
type F0 = () => any
type F1 = (x: any, ...xs: any[]) => any

function f<F extends F0>(f: F): void
function f<F extends F1>(f: F, xs: Parameters<F>): void
```

This doesn't quite work, giving following results:

```
f(() => {}) // ok
f((a: number) => {}, [2]) // ok

f((a: number) => {}, ['a']) 
// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
// Good, working as expected

f((a: number) => {})
// Error: Argument of type '(a: number) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'F0'
// So it sees this as the first overload. It doesn't ask for a missing second arg.
// Technically, suits my goals, but in a kinda wrong way.

f(() => {}, []) // ok (!)
// Somehow it sees this as valid application of the second overload, 
// regardless of parameters count
```

The thing is, `F0 extends F1 ? true : false` gives result of `true` – that's why last case is recognized as the second overload.

I understand that there is nothing wrong here, it's a correct behaviour for TS.

But is it even possible to solve my task then?

Comment: There are a lot of potential edge cases here; what do you want to see when the callback is of a type like `(x?: number) => void` where there's 0 or 1 params?  Or a type like `(...args: number[]) => void` where there's any number of params?

Comment: Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJA5vm) would meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75452181/typescript-overload-based-on-a-func-param-count#comment133128923_75452181) Similar to the code from @jcalz but the case on line 19 is treated as an error: https://tsplay.dev/WG2Akm

Comment: @jcalz this is perfectly fine. As for spread params – I'm not interested in this case at all; and in case with optional params, your solution denies to pass an empty array but is ok when array is not passed at all – it's exactly what I want. Would appreciate a detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to writing `f()`'s call signature is the following:

```
declare function f<A extends any[]>(
    cb: (...a: A) => any, ...rest: ArgsOrNothing<A>
): void;

type ArgsOrNothing<A> =
    [xs: A & [any, ...any]] |
    ([] extends A ? [] : never)
```

Instead of explicit [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), it is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [rest parameter tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) `A` of the callback function, and we then evaluate `ArgsOrNothing<A>` to determine whether `f()` should accept another argument or not.  Since `ArgsOrNothing<A>` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), `f()` behaves like an overloaded function.

The first possibility: `[xs: A & [any, ...any]]`, which means that `f()` accepts an additional argument of type `A & [any, ...any]]`.  The type `[any, ...any]` is a [tuple with a rest element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types), meaning it has to be known to contain at least one element.  A value of type `A & [any, ...any]` is therefore both appropriate as an argument tuple to `cb`, *and* has to contain at least one element.  That means this possibility is for calling `f(cb, xs)` with two arguments, where `xs` is non-empty.

The other possibility: `([] extends A ? [] : never)`.  This is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) that checks whether the empty argument list `[]` is assignable to `A`... in other words, whether `cb()` is an acceptable call.  If so, then `f()` should be callable with just one argument (by adding `[]` to the type of `...rest`).  If not, then `f()` should *not* be callable with just one argument (by not adding anything to the type of `...rest`; `| never` doesn't change anything).  That means this possibility is for calling `f(cb)` with one argument, in cases where `cb()` would be acceptable.

Let's test it out:

```
f(() => { }) // ok
f((a: number) => { }, [2]) // ok
f((a: number) => { }, ['a'])  // error
f((a: number) => { }) // error
f(() => { }, []) // error

const cb = (a?: number) => { }
f(cb); // okay
f(cb, [1]); // okay
f(cb, []); // error

const cb2 = (...args: string[]) => { }
f(cb2); // okay
f(cb2, ["a", "b", "c"]); // okay
f(cb2, []); // error
```

These all look good, I think.  The standard cases do what you want.  For edge cases like when `cb()` has an [optional parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) or when it is variadic, the behavior above is that you should be allowed to call it both ways, but if you want to call the underlying function `cb()` with no arguments, you must not pass a second argument to `f()`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwM4Hk4DkD2wAWBLAOwQB4YA+KAXgCgo6oBtADyQC5YoAyRgQwJAA0UAHSi+IALoSoAH1r0AFA2kQmwCAQAmSDgH5G09gQgA3CHACU1apogBjADY840AGYBXAneB5MBKK6kUKrqWjriymQK8nR2AEbsCqLCPOwwFlQU4kLJLkjAaYioGNj4RKRk1BbsJph4mgDc1q4KChmUFADeUAC+GQD0-VCYANbULQqpUATuALZx5u1dvUIMAEwSA0Oj461TM-OLmVDdPasA5Dznm3SDwXBwmHC7k0ZzC5bHp1v3j88TSxOKwMP3Mf2sdj8+Sg8SoUEmujeh0+HSBPV28QsDSgd1GPBAGLiqwAjJtsbiRvjCasyTihmCnhCocAYXE1nCkmIiux8nBCAhlIDToS1li6cNKQSWvE1qsAEQ8OVCOVxJVQOV2OW0ilU6Vsmliu4M55AA)